# Nested LESS statements when dealing with the :before and :after sudo classes

Tags: css, class, less

I have the following LESS statement that tries to put a colored background on the :after sudo class:

```
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  &.red-light {
    border-top: 50px solid @brand-red-light;
  }
  &.red {
    border-top: 50px solid @brand-red;
  }
  &.red-dark {
    border-top: 50px solid @brand-red-dark;
  }
  &.freen-light {
    border-top: 50px solid @brand-green-light;
  }
  &.green {
    border-top: 50px solid @brand-green;
  }
  &.green-dark {
    border-top: 50px solid @brand-green-dark;
  }
}
```

Only anything in the nested LESS statement eg: border-top: 50px solid @brand-red-light does not make it to the screen when rendered. I have tried taking out the "&" sign and replacing it with an ">" but no luck. I am trying to draw a hexagon with CSS.

Comment: put your :after content into a child that's &:after {} and that might work

Comment: `freen-light` should probably be `green-light`.

Comment: If hungerstar's answer doesn't solve your problem, please add the HTML markup to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LESS is creating the following CSS selectors:

```css
.hexagon:after
.hexagon:after.red-light
.hexagon:after.red
.hexagon:after.red-dark
.hexagon:after.green-light
.hexagon:after.green
.hexagon:after.green-dark
```

I think you meant to generate this:

```css
.hexagon:after
.hexagon.red-light:after
.hexagon.red:after
.hexagon.red-dark:after
.hexagon.green-light:after
.hexagon.green:after
.hexagon.green-dark:after
```

If so reconfigure your LESS to the following:

```css
.hexagon {
    &:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -50px;
        left: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 100px solid transparent;
        border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    }    
    &.red-light:after {
        border-top: 50px solid @brand-red-light;
    }
    &.red:after {
        border-top: 50px solid @brand-red;
    }
    &.red-dark:after {
        border-top: 50px solid @brand-red-dark;
    }
    &.green-light:after {
        border-top: 50px solid @brand-green-light;
    }
    &.green:after {
        border-top: 50px solid @brand-green;
    }
    &.green-dark:after {
        border-top: 50px solid @brand-green-dark;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted. Sorry for the confusion of my question. Your answer is so simple and elegant. I didn't know the sudo class could be expressed as you did. Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: No problem, in Less `&` represents the current selector parent/path. Think of it as a variable that contains the current selector and gets added onto each time you nest.